# S4 Object Issue with scale_shape_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, shapes

I am struggling with an issue with scale_shape_manual and scale_colour_manual from ggplot. Retaking the example from ggplot help(scale_colour_manual) we get the following two lines :

```
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))
p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))
```

They work fine and I can do whatever I want after that. But if I decide to create a line like this one, which would create an object combining the layers

```
h <- p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))
```

Then any command will prompt me an warning message "Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("manual", "discrete", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object". Even a very simple one :

```
 a = 2
```

However If I recompile the last line it works. Anyone had the same issue ? Can you help me on that ?

Following comment here is a reproducible example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)
data(mpg)
p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))
h  <-  p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))
a = 2
```

UPDATE - 
Apparently it was just a version issue, the following version appear not to work together :  R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) Hmisc_3.14-3 and ggplot2_0.9.3.1. One might consider detach(package:Hmisc, unload = TRUE) or just accept the warning.

Thanks
R

Comment: What are the exact steps to reproduce the error? I've run the lines you've typed above without any problems.

Comment: The following lines create an error  
    data(mpg)
    p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))  
    h  <-  p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))  
    a = 2`  
I get the error : 1: In class(y) <- class(x) :
  Setting class(x) to multiple strings ("manual", "discrete", ...); result will no longer be an S4 object

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. My wild guess is that you've installed some odd combination of R/ggplot2 versions, or done something else to your R session to create this problem. Include the output of `sessionInfo()` in your question, and try again in a fresh R session.

Comment: Following the comments @joran I was able to pinpoint the issue, I have the library Hmisc included the following should create the error : 
`
    library(ggplot2)
    library(Hmisc)
    data(mpg)
    p <- qplot(mpg, wt, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))
    h  <-  p + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","blue", "green"))
    a = 2
`
I mainly use the Hmisc library for its "inc" function which I find usefull to do an equivalent in R to +=. I could not use it but would rather find a solution that includes it. 

Thanks 
R3

Comment: So, that's not an error, that's a warning (there's a big difference). The warning is actually being thrown in the `h <- ...` line, but I'm honestly not sure why.

Comment: Sorry you're right it is a warning. I updated the question. I might just use `detach(package:Hmisc, unload = TRUE)` before the procedure

Comment: I tried the code above with Hmisc (3.14-4) and ggplot2 (1.0.0) with R 3.0.2 and could not reproduce. Must be a bad version combination.

Comment: You're probably right. I was using R version 3.0.3 (2014-03-06) Hmisc_3.14-3 and ggplot2_0.9.3.1. I am closing the thread thanks for your help.